# Activate Bluetooth SPP in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to use Bluetooth SPP to communicate over it. In some Android phones, SPP profile is not activated. I faced the problem in the application that SPP was not activated and so the connection could not be established over bluetooth and when I started another app that is 3g hotspot which I think activates SPP and I was able to connect over bluetooth in my app.

So, how can we actually activate SPP profile of bluetooth in Android devices? And does all the android devices has SPP profile?

Answer (score 13):

In developer.android.com [BluetoothSocket](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html):

> The most common type of Bluetooth
>   socket is RFCOMM, which is the type
>   supported by the Android APIs. RFCOMM
>   is a connection-oriented, streaming
>   transport over Bluetooth. It is also
>   known as the Serial Port Profile
>   (SPP).

Comment: Can we use SPP for Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE) devices ?

Comment: @MyGod SPP is only for BT Classic

Answer (score 7):

This might answer your question ..
https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/services

SPP (or ability to use Java API's to establish RFCOMM channels) is available from Android (2.0/2.1) release (Eclair) onwards

On the Android phone you will probably need to run an application that initiates the service over SPP.
**

> public BluetoothServerSocket
> listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord
> (String name, UUID uuid)

** API can be used to create a service with specified UUID to listen,
Doing this should make this service visible to other devices which can then connect to it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that, but what I actually want is that SPP profile should be activated. Right now, if I connect my android device to my PC and look into Bluetooth settings in my PC it shows Headset profile as activated and SPP profile as deactivated. Is there any way I can activate the SPP profile programmatically?

Comment: You will probably need some applcation using the SPP service on the phone so that it is visible to connecting devices.

Comment: You can use the public BluetoothServerSocket listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord (String name, UUID uuid) API to register a service, then from the PC you should see this under SPP profile.

Comment: Can we use SPP for Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE) devices ?

Answer (score -1):

I just called Samsung help regarding bluetooth SPP on an S8+ phone. They tell me wait for Android Oreo as it isn't available till then. My previous Sony Xperia used Ntrip Client to talk to an external Geneq GPS to receive corrected coordinates and worked really well. Seems we went backwards somewhere?
Ntrip client on the phone collects an internet data stream of GPS corrections every five seconds and sends these to the GPS. The GPS uses the corrections and sends back adjusted coordinates to the phone to use in any application.
I would appreciate someone brighter than me pointing out a quick fix I just load and run to bring back this functionality.