# Which Android versions support SPP class 0x00?

Tags: android, class, bluetooth, device, spp

I was wondering which Android OS versions support the Bluetooth SPP. I know the problem can be solved using certain apps like "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.zornsoftware.bluetoothclasszero&hl=pl". Nevertheless I'd like to know if people from Adnroid finally fixed this issue in any recent Android release.

Thanks for your time.

Regards!
Łukasz

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4037619/966550) answer, its available from Android 2.0 and above. For more info, read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html)

Comment: Thanks for your interest. It appears that you misunderstood the post subject. Even though it is available since Android 2.0 some devices e.g. HTC Wildfaire S (Android 2.3.3) do not list SPP Bluetooth Shields in the "detected devices" list. They simply skip a device if its class is 0x00. I'm wondering if this bug is fixed in consecutive releases of Android.